# Separating PHP session variables into their own files

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

I am thinking about writing a session handler (using session_set_save_handler) which stores each session variable in it's own file. Maybe I will have the session_id as a directory, and each variable stored in its own file, with the session key as the filename.

My purpose is:

- Non-blocking (or lesser-blocking) session. I.e. when you run a script which opens the session, you don't have to close the session before another script can write to the session. I am thinking that the session handler can quickly open and close a single file for write access (read access is ok because you can close a session and still access the values using $_SESSION). So basically to write to any given session variable, the script won't need to lock the entire session.
- The application is already quite database heavy (it's a central database for a biology research lab) hence why I don't want to put extra load on the database by storing user's sessions in the database (although this is an alternative, maybe even set up an additional database for sessions?). Sessions are used a fair bit as user's form inputs are saved to their session using ajax (on change, for persistence) and there can be multiple instances of any given form.
- Facilliate garbage collection / expiry routines on the sessions without over-locking

Does anyone have an opinion on storing sessions like this? Is it a good idea? Bad idea?

Comment: I feel like you're re-inventing the wheel here. There are plenty of session implementations out there, I'm sure some, if not many, are designed to do what you want here.

Comment: havent you thought of - in case of saving forms - of using local storage? By my experience, filesystem sessions are vulnerable and resource-heavy.

Comment: @Bulk Do you have any links? Recommendations? I am a wheel re-inventor I will admit - I am actually using my own web framework I built over the last 6 years or so haha! Reinventing the wheel is very time consuming but I don't regret it one bit in terms of the framework. As for this session stuff yeah it would be great to find a finished solution ready to use.

Comment: Have you done any research before asking here? There are plenty of articles you can read on how to implement non-blocking sessions, in fact it is high on the agenda in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @yergo It is a good suggestion, thanks. The framework has 'Components' which have a 'persistence_id' and 'component key'. Only the persistence_id is stored on the client using jquery data attr. Components can be initialised using their key (basically an array), this is what is stored in the session, identified by persistence_id. My Forms are a subclass of Component. I would need the solution to work for storing all component keys - not just form inputs. I need the keys on the server in many cases. So I am not sure I can convert it over to using local storage.

Comment: @Bonner I've been researching it a lot today yes. It seems that the 'go to' solution is to store the session in a database, at the cost of some performance. So I had this idea and I'm putting it out there into the community to see what people think.

Comment: I'd say this as a whole is a bad idea. If you allow "individual" access to session variables by parallel scripts, you WILL encounter situations where two parallel scripts will desynchronize things by changing values that shouldn't be changed separately. e.g. script #1 starts wiping the session as part of logout, script #2 updates some stuff, now you've got a partially nuked session.

Comment: Do you really have a use case where there may be multiple clients (i.e. browser instances) using the same session id?

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm not sure that was what Col was getting at, I think Col is talking about sessions causing a page to hang while the session data is read or is being written.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you avoid writing something yourself and you implement a solution which has already been tried and tested.

The following solution meets the criteria you set out in your question:

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/session_storage.html

I recommend if your application is already quite database heavy as you have stated, that you create a separate database purely for storing and reading sessions as you have acknowledged already.

In order to get set up you will have to download Silex which uses Symfony2 Components. I recommend the best way to get Silex set up on your website is to use Composer. For brevity I will not cover installing and setting up Composer as there are lots of useful articles on how to do this.

You don't have to make use of everything which comes with Silex but if you choose to go down this route having the Silex class library will probably be beneficial for other uses too.

Instructions for setting up Silex can be found at the following location:

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html

The following link provides more information on configuring sessions along with an example on how to use them, however it is mentioned on the page that file storage is used, you can ignore anything relating to file storage:

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/session.html

Despite meeting the requirements you have specified, if the recommended solution is not something you would consider please explain why and I will look to provide additional help and support where required.